# Dead By Daylight

Tags: mathematics, cipher, number-theory, number-property

This puzzle is a reference to a game, [Dead By Daylight](https://deadbydaylight.com/en). Though you don't need a knowledge about the game. Consequently, there is no "video-games" tag.

## Story

The Entity wants to have the killers' names concealed to the survivors, so **he** is going to encrypt the killers' names!

## Encryption

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Plaintext} & \text{Encrypted} \\ \hline
\text{trapper}   & \text{mayysvvsgpamdjpgjd}        \\
\text{wraith}    & \text{yimisrpidijrgiviar}     \\
\text{hillbilly} & \text{tnehqbbwnqzkkewzht}       \\
\text{nurse}     & \text{witfhun kxzlerboqc}     \\
\text{shape}     & \text{vdvjmyvvvampvmvsmg}      \\
\text{hag}       & \text{pkpegzptpnghpbpwgq}         \\
\text{doctor}    & \text{uwlwcwuwlwcwuwlwcw}        \\
\text{huntress}  & \text{pogcpipfgup pxglpr}         \\
\text{cannibal}  & \text{bjkgkvbakykmbskpkd}         \\
\text{nightmare} & \text{nzhzbhwzqzkhezzzth}         \\
\text{pig}       & \text{ehbwhtwztnzknqkeqb}         \\
\text{clown}     & \text{miafgud sxylvrjopc}         \\
\text{spirit}    & \text{jpyammaypjdvsggsvd}         \\
\text{legion}    & \text{h wobczrnftuqiexkl}         \\
\text{plague}    & \text{hbhehzhkhnhhhthwhq}         \\
\text{ghost face}& \text{cu  oxulrrfolciixf}         \\
\text{demogorgon}& \text{ejeawjejeawjejeawj}         \\
\text{oni}       & \text{kyzaembgqjwvtphsnd}         \\
\text{deathslinger}& \text{nkktqkekbthkwkttzk}         \\
\text{executioner}& \text{dkmwvzdtmevhdbmnvq}
\end{array}
$$

## Objective

Explain how the Entity encrypted the names.

## CSV Version

```
Plaintext   ,Encrypted
trapper     ,mayysvvsgpamdjpgjd
wraith      ,yimisrpidijrgiviar
hillbilly   ,tnehqbbwnqzkkewzht
nurse       ,witfhun kxzlerboqc
shape       ,vdvjmyvvvampvmvsmg
hag         ,pkpegzptpnghpbpwgq
doctor      ,uwlwcwuwlwcwuwlwcw
huntress    ,pogcpipfgup pxglpr
cannibal    ,bjkgkvbakykmbskpkd
nightmare   ,nzhzbhwzqzkhezzzth
pig         ,ehbwhtwztnzknqkeqb
clown       ,miafgud sxylvrjopc
spirit      ,jpyammaypjdvsggsvd
legion      ,h wobczrnftuqiexkl
plague      ,hbhehzhkhnhhhthwhq
ghost face  ,cu  oxulrrfolciixf
demogorgon  ,ejeawjejeawjejeawj
oni         ,kyzaembgqjwvtphsnd
deathslinger,nkktqkekbthkwkttzk
executioner ,dkmwvzdtmevhdbmnvq
```

Note that the Ghost Face's encrypted name has two spaces.

## Subtle Hint

> The Entity encrypted them by his name. What does that mean?

## Moderate Hint

> I think the Entity's real name is Joseph F______.

## Decisive Hint

> $2^{18} ≡ 1 \pmod{26+1}$

Comment: Just to clarify, are the encryptions encrypted versions of the killers nicknames as shown in the plaintext, or the killers actual names from the game?

Comment: @gabbo1092 Nicknames.

Comment: Based off the last hint, would I be correct in looking into [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) ?

Comment: @gabbo1092 Almost.

Comment: By measuring the information content of the ciphertexts with regards to the last hint, I've deduced this is something about rot13(ahzrevp onfrf).

Comment: Analysis of the decisive hint: the 18 refers to the number of characters in the ciphertexts, while the 26 obviously refers to the alphabet. Am I right @DannyuNDos?

Comment: @1357924680a Correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a partial answer, because I don't see how to reverse the "encryption", and I'm not enough of a mathematician to confidently say this transform is not reversible.

**Explain how the entity encrypted the names.**

> The entity's name is Joseph Fourier. The "encryption" method is a generalization of the Discrete Fourier Transform called the [Number-Theoretic Transform](https://www.nayuki.io/page/number-theoretic-transform-integer-dft), which substitutes complex arithmetic with arithmetic on a finite field.

[**Source code**](https://pastebin.com/4pG9WaN7)

Solve path:

> I put the hint "Joseph F" and the tag "number theory" into a Google search, which turned up Joseph Fourier and the Fourier transform. Next, I Googled up "Fourier transform for sequence of integers" and found out about the NTT. I inferred from the other hint that the 18th primitive root of unity mod 27 was 2, which gave me the parameters for the transform ($\omega=2, M=27, n=18$), and then implemented the transform in a handful of lines of Python, transforming the killers' names into their "encryptions".

> Before attacking it as a riddle, I tried using old-school cryptographic methods to analyze it. The most significant thing I could find was that by dividing each "encryption" into its even and odd positions, I saw that the same letters kept appearing in groups.

> ```
>  ghost.face.. , c.ourflix u.xlrocif
>  legion...... , hwbzntqek .ocrfuixl
>  clown....... , magdsyvjp ifu.xlroc
>  huntress.... , pgppgppgp ocifu.xlr
>  nurse....... , wthnkzebq ifu.xlroc
>
>  spirit...... , jymapdsgv pamyjvgsd
>  trapper..... , mysvgadpj ayvspmjgd
>
>  oni......... , kzebqwthn yamgjvpsd
>  wraith...... , ymspdjgva iiriiriir
>
>  hillbilly... , teqbnzkwh nhbwqkezt
>  pig......... , ebhwtznkq hwtznkqeb
>  deathslinger , nkqebhwtz ktkktkktk
>  nightmare... , nhbwqkezt zzhzzhzzh
>  hag......... , ppgppgppg keztnhbwq
>
>  shape....... , vvmvvmvvm djyvapmsg
>
>  cannibal.... , bkkbkkbkk jgvaymspd
>  plague...... , hhhhhhhhh bezknhtwq
>  demogorgon.. , eeweeweew jajjajjaj
>  executioner. , dmvdmvdmv kwztehbnq
>
>  doctor...... , ulculculc wwwwwwwww
> ```

> Note the line for `doctor` which appears to have very little information in it, barely enough to encode the word. Also note groups like `ayvspmjgd` and `.ocrfuixl` where the distance between each pair of adjacent letters (`ay`, `yv`, `vs`...) is identical when counted along a 27-letter alphabet which includes a space. These groups must also encode very little information.